# Can't login into ubuntu 12.04 computer before login timesout

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, login

I have an ubuntu 12.04 server. My password is long and before I can fully enter the password, the login timesout. I can't get into the box to change this timeout time. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

reBoot your linux box in single mode. 
Simply, before boot, at the grub prompt, edit the kernel line and append "single" word to the end of line (without quotes). Your server will boot with a root shell. After that change the user password or change the

LOGIN_TIMEOUT       60

line in /etc/login.defs

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the password to the clipboard, log in via SSH and then paste it when prompted.

Comment: I don;t have ssh on it